# Создание отчёта в PDF и html

Tags: c#, html, c++, pdf

Есть программа которая рассчитывает параметры и нужно создать отчёт по завершение расчета программы с помощью кнопки сохранить 
Нужно что бы создавал отчёт по расчетам и выводил все данные 
Нужно создать html и PDF файлы в которых все будет находиться и так же что бы в них можно было вставить графики 
Программу делал на C# 
Не знаю как и с помощью чего сделать такие отчёты подскажите пожалуйста

Сам вопрос 
Как можно сделать отчёты в html и PDF формате

Comment: html очень просто, открывается файл, как простой текстовый (с расширением html)  и заполняется на этом языке разметки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отчет в pdf-формате можно сформировать с помощью библиотеки iText. Теги для разметки html-документа несложно сформировать самостоятельно.